# Google Scripts "Utilities.formatDate" does nothing with the time zone parameter

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, date-formatting

This 2 lines generate the same output:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "ET", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
```

Output:

```
2:20:37 PM Info -> 2022-01-26T19:20:37Z
2:20:37 PM Info -> 2022-01-26T19:20:37Z
```

Doesn't matter the input, is always converting the date to UTC (probably), this makes impossible to print the correct date and time.

What is the correct way to format a date-time in Google Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ET" is not an accepted time zone name.

For that you would use 'America/New_York'.

Apps Script's documentation doesn't call that out, which can be frustrating to non-developers. Here is the list of all the [timeZone ids](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/8673e904a03a91750c26c2754fe0977a)

Also, by putting the '' around the Z, it treats it as a string and just returns the date with a Z.  I know that is what is in the example on the apps script page, but it is wrong.

Try this:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z"));
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"));
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z"));
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"));
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"));
```

Comment: "wacky"? "America/New_York" is an [IANA Time Zone](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) name, the standard for time zone names for computers for years... And a better list to link to would be [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Correct, but for those of us that came in from a non developer background, it is really hard, and very frustrating, to figure that out.

Comment: @Kris—it will be a lot more frustrating if it attempted to use common timezone name abbreviations since they are not standardised or unique (e.g. EST can apply to 3 different timezones). Also, the IANA locations take historic offset and daylight saving changes into account.

Comment: Good points, I updated the answer.